# My component is creating TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: reactjs

[image]

This problem is related with my **Buy_Item Component**. The Urban Outfitter logo at the top left is supposed to bring you back to the home page. It works completely fine with my other components, except this one. When I click it gives me:

[image]

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Header/>
          <Route exact path="/" render = {() => <Featured/> } />

          <Route path="/items-available" render = {() => <Items_Available item_info={<Item_Info/>}/> } />

          <Route path="/buy-item" render = {() => <Buy_Item buy_item_info={<Buy_Item_Info/>}
            item_info={<Item_Info/>}/> } />

          <Footer/>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's what the "Urban Outfitter" logo does in my **Header Component**:

```
        <div id="nav_logo_container">
          <Link to="/">
            <picture>
              <source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset={uo_logo} />
              <source srcset={uo_logo_smaller_screen} />
              <img id="nav_logo" src={uo_logo} alt="Urban Outfitters Logo" />
            </picture>
          </Link>
        </div>
```

Here's my Github repo, if it helps: https://github.com/mattfrancis888/project_2/tree/item_info/src

Comment: Why do you have `ref={this.simulateClick}` in your Buy_Item component? Also, you should post the code here, not link to GitHub.

Comment: The ref is so when the user enters the page. The radio button which will appear for small screens (at the top of the image)  is instantly clicked! I figured the code I posted above is enough, but the remote might be helpful if I'm leaving out anything crucial, which I don't think I am

Comment: Well your ref is trying isn't going to get the `e` event value, which is causing the error.

Comment: Wow you are absolutley right. The ref was causing the error, despite it not saying in the error statement.  What made you think the ref was the issue by just looking at the error statement?

Comment: Well, I saw that `.click()` was the issue, and the only place that's used is in the `this.simulateClick` function, which expects an `event` but which is called from a ref so will never have an `event` passed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it all wrong in your `Buy_Item` component

Never call `setState` inside the `render()` method as it could cause an infinite loop. This is because calling `setState` will always lead to a re-render unless `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `false`.

Try this...

```
const imgDic = {
  0: item_1,
  1: item_1_alt,
  2: item_1_alt2,
  3: item_1_alt3,
  4: item_1_alt4,
  5: item_1_alt5
};

class Buy_Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      radioStatus: null,
      currentImg: item_1
    };
    this.handleRadioClick = this.handleRadioClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleRadioClick(radioId) {
    this.setState({
      radioStatus: radioId,
      currentImg: imgDic[radioId]
    });
  }

  render() {
    // the rest of render code goes here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! But by doing that, I get a handleRadioClick is not defined error now

Comment: Ahh, i think I know where the error is from. Inside the render method, change `handleRadioClick` to `this.handleRadioClick` @MatthewFrancis

Comment: Also, if you're using React v16, you should read up on React.createRef to understand refs.

Comment: I'll give it a try! and regarding my refs, is it deprecated or some sort? It works as of now, but I'm assuming it's bad practice?

Comment: It depends on the version of React that you're using. On older versions, it usually is created like this - `<input ref={node => this.inputRef = node } />` but in v16, you do this in the constructor - `this.inputRef = React.createRef()`, then in your render, you do `<input ref={this.inputRef} />`

Comment: Awesome! Apparently, it's the refs that are the problem to my post; if you remove it, the code works fine. Also. Are you able to put refs on <spans>? For example : https://gyazo.com/0910d48633a5a6779451890d548d8e6a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193228/discussion-between-ladi-aden-and-matthew-francis).